# Inverse of `sequence` from Data.Traversable in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I need a function of type `Monad m => m [a] -> [m a]`, which works just as `sequence` does, but in reverse.

I've tried searching for any function with this type signature on Hoogle, but there doesn't seem to exist any. Is it impossible in general? Should I be avoiding this type of construction to begin with?

Comment: The answer below (you can't do this) is probably about the best we can say; but this smells like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). Perhaps you can open another question discussing how you came to the conclusion that you want this operation; then we may be able to suggest an alternative that helps with what you actually want to do.

Comment: @user3237465 Good eye!

Comment: @DanielWagner You're right. I managed to work around it. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There can be no such function, because not every monad admits a kind of "exit function" `m a -> a`. `IO` exemplifies this: if you have an `IO a`, you cannot remove the `IO` constructor (except via `unsafePerformIO` which you probably don't want to use).

The monad typeclass functions

```
return :: a -> m a
(>>=) :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

each have an `m a` after the rightmost arrow, so without more constraints on your function, the `m` constructor cannot be removed from around the list `[a]`.